# "do we" in a non-question statement

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

From https://www.businessinsider.sg/ceos-from-these-6-universities-led-most-ipos-this-year-2019-10/?r=US&IR=T

> 2019 has been filled with some notable initial public offerings, but
>   rarely **do we** stop to consider which universities the executives of
>   these companies hail from – or if they attended college at all.

Is the **do we** here grammatical and idiomatic? My impression is that **do we** is always used within a question.

Comment: Yes, this order of the words in this sentence is grammatically and idiomatically correct. This is normal in English and it is called **subject-verb inversion**.

Comment: It's the presence of the fronted negator "rarely" that triggers subject-auxiliary inversion.